# Replace php help me

Tags: php

Помогите составить preg_replace() который будет все ссылки сводить к слову "спам")

Comment: пример текста можно в студию?

Comment: Заходи http://example.com и побеждай

Comment: Либо просто линк

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$text = '123 https://ru.stackoverflow.com 123';
$pregr = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
echo preg_replace($pregr, "<SPAM>", $text);
```

Comment: а что если у нас после ссылки либо нет ничего либо текст какой)

Comment: @ДмитрийТерещук так проверьте сперва) а потом уж говорите `что если`. Либо можете привести конкретный пример где не работает.

Comment: Немного модернизировал и вообще хорошо))